# Preserve data type when concatenating Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, types

I want to concatenate two dataframes - one dataframe as "integer" data type, while the other dataframe has "float" datatype.
Here, `mut` data frame is originally integer, whereas `mirna` is float.
The combined data frame coerced all the values into float.

```
mut.insert(len(mut.columns), "category", 0, True)
mut = mut.dropna()

mirna.insert(len(mirna.columns), "category", 1, True)
mirna = mirna.dropna()

df = pd.concat([mut, mirna])
```

`mut`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {'IGF2R': 1, 'NBEA': 1, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 1},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0}})
```

`mirna`

```
{'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.436967295678264,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.6676128143486753,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.958120697018377,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.3710754357912336},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 1.8616291060705468,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.5952286310865538,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.7737597007222166,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.4958162915921864},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.13165245798285,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.682127909644228,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.914741202547229,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.5227245438834998},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.1191074673269097,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.6612699717201993,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 2.123077968206283,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.5324296559039428}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, all the values in a DataFrame column can only be represented as a single type, which is why the `int` values are converted to `float` values.

However, as a work around, you could represent each column as the base type `object`. You would first have to convert the columns of each DataFrame before you use `.concat()`. This can be accomplished using the [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method.

#### Code

```py
# The columns to convert to objects.
cols = ['TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A']
# Alternatively to get the first 4 columns: cols = df.columns[:5]

# For each DataFrame convert these columns to the type 'object'.
mut[cols] = mut[cols].astype(object)
mirna[cols] = mirna[cols].astype(object)

# Concatenate the arrays
df = pd.concat([mut, mirna])
```

#### Inputs

`mut`:

```
      TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A  category
IGF2R                1                0                0                0         0
NBEA                 1                0                0                0         0
KMT2D                0                0                0                0         0
HERC2                0                0                1                0         0
```

`murna:`

```
              TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A  category
hsa-let-7a-3p         2.436967         1.861629         2.131652         2.119107         1
hsa-let-7b-5p         3.667613         3.595229         3.682128          3.66127         1
hsa-let-7b-3p         1.958121          1.77376         1.914741         2.123078         1
hsa-let-7c-5p         3.371075         3.495816         3.522725          3.53243         1
```

#### Output

```
              TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A  category
IGF2R                        1                0                0                0         0
NBEA                         1                0                0                0         0
KMT2D                        0                0                0                0         0
HERC2                        0                0                1                0         0
hsa-let-7a-3p         2.436967         1.861629         2.131652         2.119107         1
hsa-let-7b-5p         3.667613         3.595229         3.682128          3.66127         1
hsa-let-7b-3p         1.958121          1.77376         1.914741         2.123078         1
hsa-let-7c-5p         3.371075         3.495816         3.522725          3.53243         1
```

Output of `df.info()`:

```
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------            --------------  -----
 0   TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A  8 non-null      object
 1   TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A  8 non-null      object
 2   TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A  8 non-null      object
 3   TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A  8 non-null      object
 4   category          8 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 384.0+ bytes
```